# Java-C++ binding: How to GetOjectClass of a stored jobject without crashing?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Goal:

- Bind the C++ class `Buf` to the Java class `Bug`
- Let the C++ `Buf` call a method of the Java `Bug`
- Don't crash (How?)

Purpose:

- Route `std::cout` to a text field in an android app
- Bind a C++ `stringbuf` to a Java `OutputStream`

Java `Bug`:

- Constructor of Java `Bug` would construct a C++ `Buf`
- Java `Bug` passes its `JNIEnv` and `jobject` to C++ `Buf`.
- Java `Bug` contains a pointer to the C++ `Buf`
- Java `Bug`'s `beep()` method calls the C++ `Buf::beep()`

C++ `Buf`:

- Stores the `JNIEnv` and `jobject` from the Java `Bug`
- `Buf::beep()` crashes when it tries to find the java class of the `jobject`

`MainActivity.java`:

- Make new project with the `Native C++ template`
- Android Studio
- Boring

Error:

```
A/org.so.buggy: runtime.cc:663] 
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: 
    use of invalid jobject 0xffbdfb78 from 
    void org.so.buggy.Bug.beep()

    --------- beginning of crash
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid
6865 (org.so.buggy), pid 6865 (org.so.buggy)
```

Bug.java:

```java
package org.so.buggy;

// Wrapper for the C++ Buf
public class Bug {
    public Bug() {
        init();
    }
    public native void beep();  // <- Crash here
    private native void init(); // Construct Buf
    private long nativeHandle;  // Pointer to Buf
}
```

native-lib.cpp:

```cpp
#include <jni.h>

class MyBuf {
public:
    MyBuf(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) :
            _env(env), _obj(obj) {
        _env->GetObjectClass(_obj); // no crash
    };

    void beep() {
        _env->GetObjectClass(_obj); // crash!
    }

private:
    JNIEnv *_env;
    jobject _obj;
};

// -- Manage the Java object's connection -- //
// -- to the C++ object (Buf)             -- //
jfieldID getHandleField(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass c = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    return env->GetFieldID(c, "nativeHandle", "J");
}

MyBuf *get_handle(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    // Get pointer to C++ Buf from the Java object
    jlong handle = env->GetLongField(obj, getHandleField(env, obj));
    return reinterpret_cast<MyBuf *>(handle);
}

void set_handle(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, MyBuf *instance) {
    // Java object's handle = pointer to C++ Buf
    jlong handle = reinterpret_cast<jlong>(instance);
    env->SetLongField(obj, getHandleField(env, obj), handle);
}

extern "C" void
Java_org_so_buggy_Bug_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    auto *instance = new MyBuf(env, obj);
    set_handle(env, obj, instance);
}

// ---- The beep that crashes the app ---- //
extern "C" void
Java_org_so_buggy_Bug_beep(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    auto *p = get_handle(env, obj);
    p->beep();
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
package org.so.buggy;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {System.loadLibrary("native-lib");}
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bug b = new Bug();
        b.beep();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a previous `JNIEnv*`. Use the most recent one (in this case the one you receive in `Java_org_so_buggy_Bug_beep`). Also, when saving `jobject`s like that, you should probably create a global reference to it (with `NewGlobalRef`), and delete the global reference once you no longer need it.

Comment: The `NewGlobalRef` bit sounds like reference counting in Python. Why reusing a previous `JNIEnv*` is bad?

Comment: That's mainly because a `JNIEnv` holds per-thread state, so they mustn't be shared across threads. You may not have more than one thread in your current code, but that could change. So it's better to just use the appropriate `JNIEnv*` for each thread.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni for a bit more info about different kinds of references, how to deal with native threads, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question.

Answer (score -1):

U can Add Try{} catch{}.with these u can stop crashing your software and run smoothly

Comment: Explaining my downvote: adding try/catch will not solve corruption in JNI caused by reusing `JNIEnv` objects and improper storage of local `jobject` references.